# Sketch App Paint Blending OpenGLES

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Can anyone suggest why my low opacity painting does this weird blending, while the SketchBookX app does it perfect?

In both images attached the vertical strokes on the left are done at full opacity, the strokes on the right are done at low opacity. The top image is mine and as you can see the strokes on the right at low opacity turn a orange-red color and don't blend/mesh with the full opacity strokes. But the SketchBookX app blends perfectly and maintains the same color.

I'm using `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` and have tried many variations with no luck, so I'm starting to think there are other things that are giving me this problem.

Do I need to handle this problem in the fragment shader? I currently have this,`gl_FragColor = color * rotatedTexture;` I'm using PNGs for brush textures.

UPDATE: Im getting the same results without using a texture. `gl_FragColor = color;`

[image: My Image]

[image: Sketchbook App]

[image: add vs subtract]

I want it to be like mixing ink, not like mixing light :)

Comment: ... with `rotatedTexture` being a value with R=G=B=1, A=<whatever>, whether sourced from a `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` texture, a suitably formed `GL_RGBA` texture or elsewhere? Which, per your blend mode, has premultiplied alpha?

Comment: Hey Tommy thanks for your reply, I not sure what you are asking or suggesting. The PNGs I'm using are 128x128 with alpha channels.

Comment: Obviously `GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` is "read the background, multiply it by 1-alpha, add it to the foreground"; it assumes the foreground colour has been multiplied by alpha prior to being stored. If you already tried `GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` and still got the wrong results, as implied by your "hav[ing] tried many variations" then you can rule that out as a possible problem. (and presumably every pixel in the PNG is pure white, ignoring the alpha?)

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand it more. And no, The PNG is not pure white. It is white in the center and blends to transparent to simulate a paint brush. (I'll upload an image soon from my computer.)

Comment: Brush PNG added. 

The result I'm looking for is like SketchBookX for iPhone. Or real life painting when color gets added to a canvas in different amounts/opacity.

Comment: I found out the same behaviour is present in Apple's GLPaint sample for iOS7. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675613/unmodified-ios7-apple-glpaint-example-blending-issue